# The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. WCF Error

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

we have recently change one of our .asmx service to .svc
the issue we are facing is we are unable to call the service from :
1. an application hosted on the same server as the .svc
2. an application hosted on different server then .svc

it gives the following error:

1. Same server error:
   **"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. "**
2. Different Server error: 
   **There was no endpoint listening at https://abc.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action**

We tried putting the certificate in the Trusted root folder and here is the error:

1. Same server error:
   **"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. "**
2. Different Server error:  **An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail**

   **Here are config settings we have:
   Config details:**

   **Hosting Config**

   **Consumer config details [Different Server]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we figured our the issue to be one of the SSL certificate on the Hosting server:

We were calling the following website of the host:

https://example.com/qwerty.svc

the web-appPool **example.com** under IIS should have a SSL certificate binded to it, and the name of the certificate should be exactly same as **example.com**

In our case the name was a mismatch, which was causing the above error.